# Remove part of a string after a character until a charcter and repeat until the string end

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to filter part of a string until it reaches a specific character and repeat until the end of string.

Data loooks like

```
095930
CF0010+EN
060983+PS
086588+GG;086326+GG
900010;
CF0002;;CF0018;
```

Output should be

```
095930
CF0010
060983
086588;086326
900010;
CF0002;;CF0018;
```

I tried the following:

```sql
SUBSTRING(column, 1, CHARINDEX('+',column+ '+', 1)-1)
```

But this removes everything after the `+` which is not what I need.

Comment: Are you really using 2008 and 2012? Have you considered updating to a supported version? You probably are going to have a struggle here because it looks like you have multiple values in a single tuple. I am guessing that the semicolon indicates the end of the value? Depending on which version of sql server you are actually using the answer will be different.

Comment: I'm using sql server2012. The semicolon is not always present at the end of the value.

Comment: So you have delimited data in your table but the delimiter is not always present. Yikes!!!

Comment: Also, you desperately need to update a supported version of sql server. It will no longer be supported in less than 2 months and hasn't received any updates in nearly 5 years.

Comment: Upgrade is planned to be done by end of May'22. Is there a way I can acheive the desired output?

Comment: Well one thought is to use STRING_SPLIT. But you don't have that in 2012, it was released in sql server 2016. This means you are likely going to be coding a solution to this twice. But to me the real solution would be to fix the design and stop storing multiple values in a tuple. That violates 1NF and makes this way more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: You need to show your effort. What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: Even with `STRING_SPLIT`, if you're not on Azure SQL Database or 2022 then i wouldn't want to use it, as it could change the order of the data. You can't even use a JSON Splitter in 2012. You'd have to use a CLR function or something like `DelimitedSplit8K` to split the data, `LEFT` it, and then reaggregate with "Ye Olde `FOR XML PATH`e (and `STUFF`)". Blarg...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing everything after and including a character in a value is quite simple, just use `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`:

```sql
LEFT(DS.Item,CHARINDEX('+',DS.Item + '+')-1)
```

The *real* problem you have is a little more complex:

1. You have a denormalised design, making this far more difficult.
2. You want to retain the denormalised design in the results, making this difficult again
3. You are using a version of SQL Server that is *very* close to end of support that has *no* in built support for string splitting and aggregation.

Saying that, unless you were using Azure SQL Database (or somehow had a copy of SQL Server 2022) I wouldn't suggest `STRING_SPLIT`, as it doesn't provide an ordinal position parameter. Though `STRING_AGG` would make things far easier; and you could use a JSON splitter too.

Instead I use [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) here, and then "Ye Olde `FOR XML PATH`e (and `STUFF`)" for the string aggregation. This gives this clunky solution:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('095930'),
            ('CF0010+EN'),
            ('060983+PS'),
            ('086588+GG;086326+GG'),
            ('900010;'),
            ('CF0002;;CF0018;'))V(YourString);

GO

SELECT YT.YourString,
       STUFF((SELECT ';' + LEFT(DS.Item,CHARINDEX('+',DS.Item + '+')-1)
              FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.YourString,';') DS
              ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(8000)'),1,1,'') AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT; 
     

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

If you *were* using Azure SQL Database (or SQL Server 2022) then the answer would be much simpler:

```sql
SELECT YT.YourString,
       STRING_AGG(LEFT(SS.Value,CHARINDEX('+',SS.Value + '+')-1),';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.Ordinal) AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(YT.YourString,';',1) SS
GROUP BY YT.YourString; --Assuming YourString has a unique value
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I made a mistake and answered this pertaining to SSIS and answered as if you were loading this data originally. I am leaving it though because SSIS is a complimentary tool of SQL Server.

To do what you ask...

Script Component:

```
var firstSplit = Row.[your Column].Split(';');

List<string> formatedCols = new List<string>();
foreach(var col in firstSplit)
    formatedCols.Add(col.Split('+')[0]);

Row.[Output Column Name] = string.Join(";", formatedCols.ToArray());
```

I would recommend a child table though with a 1 to many relationship to parent.